# What exactly is Green's Function and why can I use it to solve harmonic oscillator problems?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, greens-function

**My question:**

> What exactly is Green's Function and why can I use it to solve
>   harmonic oscillator problems? In other words, how is Green's function
>   connected to physics problems like the harmonic oscillator?

**My question is motivated by a bonus question on my worksheet:**

A undamped, harmonic oscillating mass $m$ with frequency $\omega_0$ is excited by an external time dependent impulse $F(t)$:

$$F(t)= 
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $t \le 0$} \\
f_0\sin{\Omega t}, & \text{if $0\le t \le T=\frac{2\pi}{\Omega}$}\\
0, & \text{if $t \ge T$}
\end{cases}$$

find $x(t)$ of the driven harmonic oscillation by using Green's Function.

Can someone explain to me what Green's function is and how I can use it to solve this question?

If some of the moderators think this question is better suited for physics stack exchange, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll restrict the context a little bit. If you have a homogeneous linear 2nd order ODE $y''+ay'+by=0$ with constant coefficients (something like the harmonic oscillator equation $y''+ky=0$), the Green's function $g$ is the solution to the problem

$$g''+ag'+bg=0,g(0)=0,g'(0)=1.$$

The Green's function is useful because the solution to the problem

$$y''+ay'+by=f,y(0)=0,y'(0)=0$$

turns out to be

$$\int_0^t g(t-s) f(s) ds.$$

Thus by adding an appropriately chosen homogeneous solution, you can solve the general problem

$$y''+ay'+by=f,y(0)=y_0,y'(0)=y_1.$$

This generalizes to essentially all linear ODEs, with some modifications. If you want to see those I can explain them, but this is enough for your question.

Edit: this method turns out to be a bit ugly for this problem. The issue is partly that the forcing gets turned off partway through the process. A nice technique in this sort of situation is the Laplace transform method. Another tool which helps us when we use trigonometric forcing is to write it as the real or imaginary part of the corresponding complex exponential.

With that in mind, start with

$$my''+ky=(1-\theta(t-T))\sin(\Omega t),y(0)=0,y'(0)=0.$$

This is the imaginary part of the solution to $mz''+kz=(1-\theta(t-T))e^{i \Omega t}$. If you take Laplace transforms on both sides and solve for $Z$, you get

$$Z=\frac{1-e^{-Ts} e^{i \Omega T}}{(s-i \Omega)(ms^2+k)}$$

using a Laplace transform table. Notably in your case $e^{i \Omega T}=1$. So now the problem comes down to finding the inverse Laplace transform of

$$\frac{1-e^{-Ts}}{(s-i\Omega)(ms^2+k)}.$$

It is convenient to write this as

$$\frac{1}{m} \frac{1-e^{-Ts}}{(s-i\Omega)(s+\omega_0 i)(s-\omega_0 i)}.$$

Provided $\Omega \neq \omega_0$, this can be partial fraction decomposed to

$$\frac{1}{m} \left ( 1-e^{-Ts} \right ) \left ( \frac{A}{s-i\Omega} + \frac{B}{s+\omega_0 i} + \frac{C}{s-\omega_0 i} \right ).$$

Now if $h(t)=A e^{i \Omega t} + B e^{i \omega_0 t} + C e^{-i \omega_0 t}$ then the solution is

$$z(t)=\frac{1}{m} \left (  h(t) - \theta(t-T) h(t-T) \right )$$

and as I said before $y$ is the imaginary part of $z$.

Comment: Thank you so much! So basically the "hard" part of this question is figuring out what $g(t-s)$ is? By looking at the intervals of my question, is it correct to say that i have to evaluate the integral: $$\int_0^T g(t-t')f(t') dt' =\int_0^{\frac{2 \pi}{\Omega }} g(t-t')f(t')dt'=\int_0^{\frac{2 \pi}{\Omega }} g(t-t') f_0\sin{\Omega t'}dt'$$

How can I calulate $g(t-t')$?

Comment: really g'(0) = 1 ? Why so?

Comment: @AndreasH. If you are a bit more familiar with mathematics, you would probably think about the situation through the problem $g''+ag'+bg=\delta(t),g(0)=0,g'(0)=0$, and the result is essentially saying $\delta * f = f$ where $*$ denotes convolution. Upon a little bit of playing around with distribution theory you can see that these are the same.

Comment: @bluemoon The main task is finding $g$ and computing the integral. Note that the solution is $y(t)=\int_0^t g(t-s) f(s) ds$; $t$ is a variable, so you cannot just plug in $T$, you need to compute the integral with $t$ as a parameter.

Comment: @Ian I think I understand. So how do I even start calculating what $g$ is i.e how do I find the "appropriate hom. solution" that I have to add to my differential equation?. By the way, thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: @bluemoon Well, you want $g''+kg=0,g(0)=0,g'(0)=1$. You should know the general solution to the differential equation is $c_1 \cos(\sqrt{k} t)+c_2 \sin(\sqrt{k} t)$. (If not, ask another question). Now you have to solve a little system of linear equations to find $c_1,c_2$. You should find $c_1=0,c_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$, so $g(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \sin(\sqrt{k}t)$. Then the solution to $y''+ky=f,y(0)=0,y'(0)=0$ is $\int_0^t \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \sin(\sqrt{k}(t-s)) f(s) ds$. For your $f$ it is a bit ugly but doable.

Comment: @bluemoon Oh, I made a small mistake: you have $m$ which might not be $1$. However you are given $\omega_0$. So you should replace my $\sqrt{k}$s with $2 \pi \omega_0$ (the $2 \pi$ converts from ordinary frequency to angular frequency).

Comment: @Ian: I see, I forgot about the delta.

Comment: Yes I do know the general solution of $g''+kg=0,g(0)=0,g(0)=1$ is $c_1 \cos{(\sqrt{k}t)}+c_2 \sin{(\sqrt{k}t})$. If I replace your $\sqrt{k}$s with $2 \pi \omega_0$ can I just replace them with $\omega_0$ since both cosine and sine are $2\pi$-periodic functions? The integral $$\int_0^t \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \sin{\sqrt{k}(t-s)}f_0 \sin{\Omega s}ds$$

looks tricky but at least it will give me something to work with or maybe I can solve it with wolfram alpha.

Comment: Just a small question regarding an earlier comment. Why can't I write the integral as $$\int_0^{\color{red}{T}}...$$

am I not integrating from $0$ to $T$?

Comment: @bluemoon No you can't just replace $2 \pi \omega_0$ with $\omega_0$. Anyway, in this case $\int_0^t g(t-s) f(s) ds$ is $\int_0^{\min \{ t,T \}} \frac{1}{2 \pi \omega_0} f_0  \sin(2 \pi \omega_0(t-s)) \sin(\Omega s) ds$. The point is that the system only responds to the force that has already happened to it, so if $t<T$ then you don't integrate up to $T$. Once $t \geq T$ all the force has already been put into the system, but the system still shuffles the energy that it has around, so it doesn't just stay constant thereafter.

Comment: @bluemoon As for how to do the integral, use the formula $\sin(a)\sin(b)=\frac{\cos(a-b)-\cos(a+b)}{2}$ and the formula $\cos(c+d)=\cos(c)\cos(d)-\sin(c)\sin(d)$.

Comment: I am not getting this integral. Using the frist trig identity you suggested I get: $$\sin{(2\pi \omega_0(t-s)-\Omega s)}\sin{(\Omega s)}=\frac{\cos{(2\pi \omega_0(t-s)-\Omega s)}-\cos{(2\pi \omega_0(t-s)+\Omega s)}}{2}$$

Comment: Applying the second trig identity:

$$\frac{\cos{(2\pi \omega_0(t-s))}\cos{(\Omega s)}+\sin{(2\pi \omega_0(t-s))} \sin{(\Omega s)}-\cos{(2\pi \omega_0(t-s))}\cos{(\Omega s)}+\sin{(2\pi \omega_0(t-s))} \sin{(\Omega s)}}{2}$$

Comment: @bluemoon Ah sorry, you are right, using both of those will send you in circles. For brevity introduce $\omega=2 \pi \omega_0$, then you should have $\sin(\omega(t-s)) \sin(\Omega s)=\sin(\omega t)\cos(\omega s)\sin(\Omega s)-\sin(\omega s)\cos(\omega t)\sin(\Omega s)$. Then the pieces that only involve $t$ can be factored out. After that, for one of the terms, you can use the formula I said before; for the other one you want the formula $\sin(a)\cos(b)=\frac{\sin(a+b)+\sin(a-b)}{2}$.

Comment: If I let $2\pi \omega_0=\omega$

$$\implies \frac{f_0}{\omega}\int_0^t \sin{(\omega(t-s))}\sin{(\Omega s)} ds \\ \iff \frac{f_0}{\omega}\int_0^t [\sin{(wt)} \cos{(\omega s)}-\sin{(\omega s)} \cos{(\omega t)}]\sin{\Omega s} ds \\ \iff \frac{f_0}{\omega} \sin{(\omega t)}\int_0^t \sin{(\Omega s)}\cos{(\omega s)}ds-\frac{f_0}{\omega} \cos{(\omega t)} \int_0^t \sin{(\omega s)}\sin{(\Omega s)}ds$$

Any idea how I could simplify this further? By the way, when does the condition $T=\frac{2 \pi}{\Omega}$ come in?

Comment: @bluemoon Now $\sin(\Omega s)\cos(\omega s)$ and $\sin(\omega s)\sin(\Omega s)$ can be converted into sums with the formulas above. Also, because the forcing is only active until time $T$, $f$ becomes zero after time $T$. Thus the integrals are all up to time $\min \{ t,T \}$. This is where the value of $T$ comes into play.

Comment: Using the trig identities $\sin{(a)}\sin{(b)}=\frac{\cos{(a-b)}-\cos{(a+b)}}{2}$ and $\sin{(a)}\cos{(b)}=\frac{\sin{(a+b)+\sin{(a-b)}}}{2}$

$$\implies \frac{f_0}{2 \omega} \sin{(\omega t)}\int_0^t \sin{(\Omega s+\omega s)}ds+ \frac{f_0}{2 \omega} \sin{(\omega t)}\int_0^t \sin{(\Omega s-\omega s)}ds- \frac{f_0}{2 \omega} \cos{(\omega t)}\int_0^t \cos{(\Omega s-\omega s)}ds+\frac{f_0}{2 \omega} \cos{(\omega t)}\int_0^t \cos{(\Omega s+\omega s)}ds$$

So far so good?

Comment: Looks OK (for $t \leq T$).

Comment: This is some messy integration. Is the "general" solution of this integral known? I think I am allowed to just write that down without doing a 2 hour integral.

Comment: I just found something in my lecture notes. Could it be that the general solution is:

$$\frac{A}{\omega_1}e^{-\beta t}\theta(t) \sin{\omega_1 t}+x_0 t$$

Comment: @bluemoon The remaining integration is easy, you just have regular sine and cosine now. The difficulty was in converting to this form. And no, at least not as written, because there is no decay.

Comment: @Ian Okay I "completed" the integration and I get a pretty long term:

$$\frac{f_0}{2 \omega (\Omega+\omega)} \sin{(\omega t)}[1-\cos{(\Omega t+\omega t)}]+\frac{f_0}{2 \omega (\Omega-\omega)} \sin{(\omega t)}[1-\cos{(\Omega t-\omega t)}]-\frac{f_0}{2 \omega (\Omega+\omega)} \cos{(\omega t)}[\sin{(\Omega t+\omega t)}]+\frac{f_0}{2 \omega (\Omega-\omega)} \cos{(\omega t)}[\sin{(\Omega t-\omega t)}]$$

Sorry that you have to spoonfeed this to me :/. I am terrible at these trig integrals.

Comment: @bluemoon That looks about right. Note that there is indeed an easier way to do the problem than with the Green's function method, which is with the Laplace transform method. (Ordinarily undetermined coefficients would be easier, but here it is a bit ugly because the forcing turns off at time $T$.) I can write up a sketched solution in this fashion if you like.

Comment: @Ian Yeah if that makes getting the solution much easier. How far away am I from reaching my final equation $x(t)$? I can't be that far away now that I have integrated.

Comment: @bluemoon You wrote the correct solution on $[0,T]$. It only remains to solve the problem with no forcing on $[T,\infty)$, which basically amounts to solving a homogeneous equation...except that you have to find the initial conditions yourself from the solution on $[0,T]$, which is a bit messy.

Comment: @Ian Ok at least "I" found one part of the solution. Can you maybe show me how to do it with Laplace for $[T,\infty]$.

Comment: @bluemoon I edited my answer. There are still some details for you to work out.

Comment: @Ian Thanks. I will try to do the other part of this question tomorrow with the method you have sketched out. It is already getting pretty late so I have to call it a day. Thank you so much for your help. Honestly, I can't thank you enough for the amount of work and time you put into answering this. Have a nice day/evening.